# How to echo output of Artisan::call() in Laravel?

Tags: php, laravel

I have a meta-command that call subcommands:

```
class Foobar extends Command
{
    protected $signature = 'foobar:foobar';

    public function handle()
    {
        $this->info('Create Foo...');
        Artisan::call('foobar:foo');

        $this->info('Create Bar...');
        Artisan::call('foobar:bar');
    }
}
```

In both `Foo` and `Bar` I have log entries such as `$this->info(...`.

Unfortunately when I call `php artisan foobar:foobar` I don't get the output of neither `foo` nor `bar`.

I got that the output can be captured with `echo Artisan::output();`, but I loose the formatting and the coloring.

Is there a way to simply echo the output as it was the same command?

Comment: Pass `$this` from your foobar:foobar command to foobar:bar and conditionally use it for output from the foobar:bar command ?

Comment: How do you pass `$this` to `Artisan::call`? Do you mean `Artisan::call('command', $this)`?

Comment: I think it would look like Artisan::call('foobar:bar', ['--calledFrom' => $this]) but check the docs to be sure.

Comment: @wheelmaker, nothing in the doc :(

Comment: https://laravel.com/docs/5.7/artisan#programmatically-executing-commands

Comment: So in my example,  you'd define a 'calledFrom' option in your foobar:bar command.